# How can I proxy without context path?

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have been using apache/sonar like this.

```
<Proxy http://localhost:7070/sonar*>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass               /sonar  http://localhost:7070/sonar nocanon
ProxyPassReverse        /sonar  http://localhost:7070/sonar
ProxyPassReverse        /sonar  http://mycompany.com/sonar
```

I've been able to serve it via `http://mycompany.com/sonar`.

SonarQube 5.4 [Dropped the ability to customize the web app context](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7122).

The option `http://sonar.mycompany.com` is not available on me. How can I make this work?